# What is the way to solve the following system of equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What are the methods of solving the following system:

$x+y+z=4$

$x^2+y^2+z^2=24$

$x^3+y^3+z^3=64$

Comment: Do you mean $z^3$ instead of $z^z$ in that last equation?

Comment: Are $x,y,z$ integers? postive? negative? real numbers?

Comment: By inspection, once can see that $(4,2,-2)$ is a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the last equation is meant to be $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 64$, we can consider squaring $(x + y + z)$:
$$16 = (x+y+z)^2 = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + 2(xy + yz + xz) = 24 + 2(xy + yz + xz)$$
and so $(xy + yz + xz) = -4$.

Similarly, we can consider cubing it instead:
$$\begin{align}(x+y+z)^3 & = & (x^3+y^3+z^3) + 3(x^2y + xy^2 + x^2z+xz^2+yz^2+y^2z)+6xyz \\ 
64 & = & 64 + 3(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)(x + y + z) - 3(x^3+y^3+z^3) + 6xyz \\
0 & = & 3 \cdot 24 \cdot 4 - 3 \cdot 64 + 6 xyz\end{align}$$

Therefore $xyz = -16$.

So where does this get us? We can now consider expanding out $(t-x)(t-y)(t-z)$ for some variable $t$. We get
$t^3 - (x+y+z)t^2 + (xy+yz+xz)t - xyz = 0$, or in other words we now need to solve $$t^3 - 4t^2 -4t + 16 =0$$

By inspection, $t = 2$ is a root, which gives us $$(t - 2)(t^2 - 2t - 8) = 0$$ and again we can factor this to give $$(t-2)(t-4)(t+2) = 0$$

So any assignment of 2, 4 and -2 to $x$, $y$ and $z$ should work.

We should check this by substituting back into the original expressions, and indeed they work!

**Edit: Motivation for considering $(t-x)(t-y)(t-z)$**

Why did I make the leap of considering $(t-x)(t-y)(t-z)$? It's mostly down to experience with working with polynomials: it's a standard fact that the coefficient of $t^i$ in that expression is the $i^{th}$ elementary symmetric polynomial in $x, y, z$. (If, for example, you study Galois theory then you'll quickly become familiar with symmetric polynomials and this fact!) This isn't hard to show, and is often taken as the definition of the elementary symmetric polynomials, in any case.

I also noticed that all the expressions given were symmetric in $x$, $y$ and $z$. This is another reason to consider the elementary symmetric polynomials: any symmetric polynomial can be written as the sum/product of elementary symmetric polynomials, so it was reasonable to hope that I could deduce information about the elementary symmetric polynomials in $x$,$y$ and $z$ given the information in the problem.

So having made the connection with symmetric polynomials, it was clear that the roots of $(t-x)(t-y)(t-z)$ were the solutions to the problem and that I had a reasonable chance of figuring out what its coefficients were given the input data to the problem.

Comment: Hi Joshua, could you explain the rationale of the step in which you use $(t-x)(t-y)(t-z)$?

Comment: I've added an explanation to the answer - let me know if that is insufficient!